# Adding anchor after automatically added UTM tracking code

Tags: discussion

Could you please explain how can I add anchor after utm code?

For example:

**My link:** `https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/#anchor`

System automatically adds `?utm_source=test&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=test` to the end of the link.

**Result:** `https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/#anchor?utm_source=test&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=test`

*Yet, I want to make it like the below to execute the anchor correctly:*

**My dream:** `https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/?utm_source=test&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=test#anchor`

Comment: This is the meta forum. You should ask this in the main one so your "dream" can come through